# Czech characters in regexp search

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to implement very simple text matcher for Czech words. Since Czech language is very suffix heavy I want to define start of the word and then just greedy match rest of the word. This is my implementation so far:

```go
    r := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)\\by\\w+\\b")
    text := "x yž z"
    matches := r.FindAllString(text, -1)
    fmt.Println(matches) //have [], want [yž]
```

I studied Go's regexp syntax:
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

but I don't know, how to define czech language characters there? Using `\w` just matches ASCII characters, not Czech UTF characters.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you mean you need to only search for words having `y` or `Y` at the start? Or do you need a more flexible solution?

Comment: Yeah, in this example yes. In more real example i want to match "uhličitá", "uhličité", "uhličitou", "uhličitého"...

Comment: @Ondra that's closer to a full-text-search match than a regex. An FTS engine can match all forms based on stemming and the language grammar. A prefix search on the other hand will suboptimal (and sometimes funny) results, especially when composite words are used. Or prefixes. You should consider using an FTS engine. Elastic provides several [language analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#greek-analyzer), including for Czech

Comment: Sometimes a regexp is not the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

In RE2, both `\w` and `\b` are [not Unicode-aware](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt):

> `\b` at ASCII word boundary («`\w`» on one side and «`\W`», «`\A`», or «`\z`» on the other)
> `\w` word characters (== `[0-9A-Za-z_]`)

A more generalized example will be to split with any chunk of one or more non-letter chars, and then collect only those items that meet your criteria:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    output := []string{}
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\P{L}+`)
    str := "x--++yž,,,.z..00"
    words := r.Split(str, -1)
    for i := range words {
        if len(words[i]) > 0 && (strings.HasPrefix(words[i], `y`) || (strings.HasPrefix(words[i], `Y`)) {
            output = append(output, words[i])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/TqCIeP62x4-).

Note that a naive approach like

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    output := []string{}
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(?:\P{L}|^)(y\p{L}*)(?:\P{L}|$)`)
    str := "x--++yž,,,.z..00..."
    matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
    for _, v := range matches {
        output = append(output, v[1])
    }
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

[won't work](https://play.golang.org/p/oLIYyRZrUPB) in case you have `match1,match2 match3` like *consecutive* matches in the string as it will only getch the odd occurrences since the last non-capturing group pattern will consume the char that is supposed to be matched by the first non-capturing group pattern upon the next match.

A workaround for the above code would be adding some non-letter char to the end of the non-letter streaks, say

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    output := []string{}
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(?:\P{L}|^)(u\p{L}*)(?:\P{L}|$)`)
    str := "uhličitá,uhličité,uhličitou,uhličitého,yz,my"
    matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(regexp.MustCompile(`\P{L}+`).ReplaceAllString(str, `$0 `), -1)
    for _, v := range matches {
        output = append(output, v[1])
    }
    fmt.Println(output)
}
// => [uhličitá uhličité uhličitou uhličitého]
```

See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/k_69OL9Zpw1).

Here, `` regexp.MustCompile(`\P{L}+`).ReplaceAllString(str, `$0 `) `` adds a space after all chunks of non-letter chars.

Comment: I knew Go has some loopholes but always had things like generics and the compiler in mind. Mixing up ASCII and Unicode in regular expressions is .... very unfortunate